# d3-generated SVG is not responsive

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive SVG.  I have successfully created an example SVG:

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 600 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" id="chart">
            <circle fill="red" cy="100" cx="100" r="100"></circle>
            <circle fill="blue" cy="100" cx="300" r="100"></circle>
            <circle fill="green" cy="100" cx="500" r="100"></circle>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsu/kombdqL2/4/

https://gist.github.com/andrewsu/d3ed340495a2f21a25f8f69dedb2096a

If you adjust the panel boundaries in the jsfiddle version, you can see the circles scaling in size appropriately.

I'd like to create the exact same SVG using D3.

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var width=600, height=200;
        var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
        .attr("id","chart")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
        .attr("viewbox", "0 0 "+ width + " " + height);
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r","100")
            .attr("cx","100")
            .attr("cy","100")
            .attr("fill","red");
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r","100")
            .attr("cx","300")
            .attr("cy","100")
            .attr("fill","blue");
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r","100")
            .attr("cx","500")
            .attr("cy","100")
            .attr("fill","green");
    </script>

</body></html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsu/g1x3s2ny/5/

https://gist.github.com/andrewsu/bf0e7549934f93ac40a416dc17bb7b1e

As near as I can tell, the rendered HTML is exactly the same, but the second example does not work correctly (see the jsfiddle).

Oddly to me, if I use my browser's inspector to change any of the four numbers in the viewBox attribute, the behavior immediately works as expected.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewBox` has an uppercase B:

```
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+ width + " " + height);
```

Check your fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/on17ga9u/

Here is the documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Comment: \*headdesk\*  Thank you

Comment: Oddly enough, if I use all lower case `viewbox` in the HTML-embedded SVG, it works fine.  So somehow it's d3 that is imposing case sensitivity...

Comment: I had the same problem. If only my eyes were case-sensitive.